# Do there exists such non constant analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Do there exists a non constant analytic function $f: \Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}$ such that $f(n)=3\quad \forall n \in \Bbb{Z}$ ?

I'm getting an intuition that such a non constant function exists, but I couldn't find the example.

Comment: Do you know one with $f(n) = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @skyking you mean $3+ \sin (z\pi)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example $f(z) = 3+\sin(z\pi)$.

In fact you can prescribe values for a analytic functions. If $a_n\to\infty$ and $c_n$ are sequences of complex numbers (where $a_n$ is an injection) there exists an analytic function such that $f(a_n) = c_n$ (this is an "advanced" result though). This fact could be used and we know there's a function such that $f(n) = 3$ and $f(n+i)=42$ for example.

At introductory level there's no reason to believe that it doesn't exists since the zeros of $f(z)-3$ doesn't have a limit point anywhere in $\mathbb C$ (it has at $\infty$ though).

Comment: Just to give the basic idea of the proof that you can. Hild your own function: you have a bunch of very thin spikes that look kinda like normal distributions that are tall enough to pickup whatever point you want.